# Why does my non-dynamic class method return dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic

The following code results in the C# compiler returning a `dynamic` type, but that class and the `GetUserProfileAsync` method are normal, 'concrete' code.

```
var profile = await this.UserProfileRepository.GetUserProfileAsync(this.ViewModel[ViewModelKeys.UserGivenName]);
```

Intellisense on the `profile` variable is absent, instead the editor/compiler says:

> This operation will be resolved at runtime.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of the parameter being passed into the `GetUserProfileAsync` method, its probably `dynamic`.

The compiler cannot thus know the type and resolve the method/callsite on the `UserProfileRepository` class.

To fix the issue, cast the value coming from `this.ViewModel` to the type you expect.

```
var profile = await this.UserProfileRepository.GetUserProfileAsync((string)this.ViewModel[ViewModelKeys.UserGivenName]);
```

Now the compiler can work it all out.